# how to find duplicates in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got duplicates by using the below query

```sql
select candidateid
from table1 table with(nolock)
where status in (1,0) 
group by candidateid, bgvtype, DepartmentId, BUId, CustomerId, ProjectId
having
    COUNT(candidateid)>1 and COUNT(bgvtype)>1 and
    COUNT(DepartmentId)>1 and COUNT(BUId)>1 and
    COUNT(CustomerId)>1 and COUNT(ProjectId)>1
```

And I got the below result when I `exec`

```sql
select * from table1 where candidateid=?
```

[image]

I should ignore 1st record since its project id is different and I need all other records for Ref. I have given one candidate id in the image but in table we have a lot of duplicates. I need to get the record "id" only when all the columns are matched

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write. Add line breaks, and indentation.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Comment: count(distinct <colname>) >1

Answer (score 0):

If you want the original rows that are duplicated on the specified columns, then you can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by candidateid, bgvtype, DepartmentId, BUId, CustomerId, ProjectId) as cnt
      from table1 t
      where status in (1,0) 
     ) t
where cnt >= 2;
```